# typescipt CSS.Properties overlapping properties

Tags: css, typescript, webpack, styles

Imagine this tsx code.

```
const parallax: CSS.Properties = {
  height: '500px',/* fallback for older browsers */
  height: '100vh',
}
```

I would like to have an overlapping property "height". But the webpack compiler raises

```
TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'height'.
```

Is there a way to do that in typescript?

Answer (score 1):

This questions seems to specifically target the [CSStype](https://github.com/frenic/csstype) library, you should mention this in your question. For fallbacks you have to use the type `PropertiesFallback`. Example from the docs:

```
import * as CSS from 'csstype';

const style: CSS.PropertiesFallback = {
  display: ['-webkit-flex', 'flex'],
  color: 'white',
};
```

Your code should look like this:

```
const parallax: CSS.PropertiesFallback = {
  height: ['500px', '100vh']
}
```

For more information please read the [docs](https://github.com/frenic/csstype#usage) carefully.

Comment: Ok, this raises another error.
Type 'PropertiesFallback<0 | (string & {}), string & {}>' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
style property in react requires you to use CSSProperties type.

Comment: @VladimirKoroteev could you add a more complete example of your file to your question? Do you import as shown in the first code snippet? Are there more styles on `parallax`? Where and how are the styles used? Maybe your package.json could also be of interest.